# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset with Hibernate But NOT eclipselink

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I am migrating a JPA application from Eclipselink to hibernate so I can use the Hibernate Criteria API and Hibernate Search.

Unfortunately occasionaly the code throw the above metioned exception even though it has not changed on the JPA provider has changed. The Error is also very random

Does anyone know what could be causing this. The main messages in the stacktrace are as stated below

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not initialize a collection: [com.farent.solutions.gateway.ui.data.User.permissions#17]

Then this as the cause
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection closed
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.checkValidity(ConnectionHolder.java:703)

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: @Jim: the last cause is clear: he's keeping the connection too long open.

Comment: Right. I didn't notice that one.

Comment: Note that EclipseLink supports the JPA 2.0 Criteria API, as well as EclipseLink Expression that are the same thing.